# How to have Different htaccess redirect based on subdirectory requested?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I tried poking around to find a question that addressed this but I didn't know the exact wording, so I couldn't find anything useful.

I have a Wordpress install on my site, following [this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/) guide, I was able to move it to a different folder so I now have 2 folders in my main public_html directory.

Im trying upload some p5.js sketches to that second folder so that I can reference them from the Wordpress  site. The problem arises when I try and link them in an iframe like [this guide](https://p5js.org/learn/tutorial-guide.html) suggests. Im referencing with `src="website.com/projects/project_name/sketch.html"` but unfortunately it gets redirected back to the wordpress installs 404 page.

After some searches, it looks like my main .htaccess file is the problem. My file looks like this (with example/my_subdir changed)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

so my question is, how would I modify this to keep the redirect from "website.com" to the my_subdir/index.php (which is the Wordpress install), but add in a caveat to not redirect website.com/directory2 requests (which is were the projects will be stored)

Answer (score 0):

If the HOST in your code `example.com` is what you refer to in your question as `website.com`, and I assume that your code is already working properly except `directory2` request. Then try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**EDITED** There is only 1 line required to be changed for directory2

Down here is my test:

> IP: 172.18.0.2
>
> Root Directory: /www/htdocs

Directory tree (html file contents):

```
-- htdocs/
 | -- my_subdir/
 |  | -- index.html (subdir index.html)
 |  | -- a1.html    (subdir a1.html)
 | 
 | -- directory2/
 |  | -- index.html (dir2 index.html)
 |  | -- b1.html    (dir2 b1.html)
 |
 | -- index.html    (helloworld index.html)
 | -- .htaccess
```

Down here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(172.18.0.2)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^(/my_subdir/)       [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^(/directory2/)      [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /my_subdir/$1

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(172.18.0.2)$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$              my_subdir/index.html  [L]
```

My Tests:

> 1. access host

```
 [user@client tmp]$ wget 172.18.0.2
 Saving to: ‘index.html’
 [user@client tmp]$ cat index.html
 subdir index.html
```

the request has reached my_subdir/index.html

> 2. access 172.18.0.2/my_subdir/a1.html

```
 [user@client tmp]$ wget 172.18.0.2/my_subdir/a1.html
 Saving to: ‘a1.html’
 [user@client tmp]$ cat a1.html
 subdir a1.html
```

the request has reached my_subdir/a1.html

> 3. access 172.18.0.2/a1.html

```
 [user@client tmp]$ wget 172.18.0.2/a1.html
 Saving to: ‘a1.html’
 [user@client tmp]$ cat a1.html
 subdir a1.html
```

the request has reached my_subdir/a1.html

> 4. access 172.18.0.2/directory2

```
 [user@client tmp]$ wget 172.18.0.2/directory2
 ...
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
 Location: http://172.18.0.2/directory2/ [following]
 ...
 Saving to: ‘directory2’
 [user@client tmp]$ cat directory2
 dir2 index.html
```

the request has reached directory2/index.html

> 5. access 172.18.0.2/directory2/b1.html

```
 [user@client tmp]$ wget 172.18.0.2/directory2/b1.html
 Saving to: ‘b1.html’
 [user@client tmp]$ cat b1.html
 dir2 b1.html
```

the request has reached directory2/b1.html

> 6. access 172.18.0.2/testerror

```
 [user@client tmp]$ wget 172.18.0.2/testerror
 ERROR 404: Not Found.
 [user@server log]$ tail error_log
 AH00128: File does not exist: /www/htdocs/my_subdir/testerror
```

the request was trying to reach my_subdir/testerror and found nothing

**So based on this small test:**

1. any request to my IP host has checked `.htaccess` rewrite rules
2. request only host will be rewrite to my_subdir/index.html (test 1)
3. request sub-url that doesn't start with `my_subdir` or `directory2` will all be rewrite to `my_subdir` with any follow up string (test 3 & 6)
4. request to `my_subdir` with detailed filename will access the file under `my_subdir/` (test 2)
5. request to `directory2` will not be redirect to `my_subdir`, and will access the index or file under `directory2` (test 4 & 5)

Comment: Sorry for late response, yes the code I posted worked to redirect any request of the website to the Wordpress install. Unfortunately I tried adding the two lines you suggested, but they did not work.

Comment: Let me just re-list the policy here: **RULE 1** The url that is accessing host `example.com`, is not `example.com/my_subdir/`, is not `example.com/directory2/`, file / directory does not exist, rewrite to `example.com/my_subdir/...`; **RULE 2** The url that is accessing host `example.com`, is not `example.com/directory2/`, rewrite to `example.com/my_subdir/index.php`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The new version in your edit works for me perfectly. Thank you so much. I really appreciate the long write-up, I'm still very new to web development, so it was very nice to use to learn.